# Не отображается слайдер в собственной теме

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Я сделала слайдер с помощью плагина Slider Revolution. Когда я добавляю шорткод на страницу стандартной темы WordPress слайдер работает. А на странице собственной темы - не отображается (место для слайдера есть, но самого слайдера нет). Подскажите, что я делаю не так. Возможно в собственную тему нужно добавить еще какой-то код 
или какие-то еще настройки.

Comment: Подробности нужны, как то... Где и как добавляли :)

Comment: Как выводите контент записи?

Comment: Сделал предположение, но нужен код.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, ответ простой: при выводе страницы вы должны убедиться, что срабатывает do_shortcode().

Стандартные функции вывода типа the_content() используют внутри эту функцию.

Оберните выводимый вами контент в do_shortcode().

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос, так как достоверно не известно, что этого не было сделано (Исходников нет).

Comment: Делаю с помощью <? Php echo do_shortcode ( '[shortcode]'); ?>, но добавляю свой шорткод. не работает.

Comment: А в каком файле вы это делаете?

Comment: Что за таинственный "свой шорткод"? Согласно правилам сообщества, создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Такая же проблема, вывожу в теле контента `[rev_slider alias="home-page"]` потом в коде делаю `<?php the_content(); ?>` - не работает, делаю через `<?php echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider alias="home-page"]'); ?>` - тоже не работает. Есть предположение, что вся проблема в том, что нет лицензии. По условиям Revolution Slider можно использовать в 2 случаях: лицензия - это очевидно, и демо-версия - только если он был предустановлен в покупной теме.

Comment: В инспекторе получаем: `.tp-revslider-mainul >li, .rev_slider >ul >li, .rev_slider >ul >li:before, .tp-revslider-mainul >li:before, .tp-simpleresponsive >ul >li, .tp-simpleresponsive >ul >li:before, .tp-revslider-mainul >li, .tp-simpleresponsive >ul >li {
    visibility: hidden;
}`

Comment: проверь наличие wp_head и wp_footer